# Haskell - Checking the Validity of a File Handle

Tags: exception, haskell, file-io, io, monads

Ok, guys, super easy question (it seems weird that Google didn't help me with this one):

```
import IO

--.... yadda, yadda, yadda

  file <- openFile "/some/path" ReadMode
```

How do I check if the handle that I got from `openFile` is a valid handle, i.e. that the file exists and was opened successfully?

Comment: BTW, don't use the module `IO` anymore, it is deprecated. Use `System.IO` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the file doesn't exist, or some other error occurs, the call to `openFile` will fail with an exception.

For example:

```
import System.IO

main = do
   openFile "/some/path" ReadMode
```

Fails with:

```
A.hs: /some/path: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

The types of exception that may be thrown by `openFile` [are listed here,](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/System-IO.html#g:5) and include:

- isAlreadyInUseError if the file is already open and cannot be reopened;
- isDoesNotExistError if the file does not exist; or
- isPermissionError if the user does not have permission to open the file.

You can catch these errors using [Control.Exception](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Control-Exception.html#g:3), like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import System.IO
import Control.Exception

main = do
    handle (\(e :: IOException) -> print e >> return Nothing) $ do
      h <- openFile "/some/path" ReadMode
      return (Just h)
```